# Python: Why do plots of functions with two variables look spurious?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am using the following code to plot a function of two variables

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from pylab import meshgrid
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(0,1.0,0.01)
y = np.arange(0,1.0,0.01)
X,Y = meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.sin(2*np.abs(X-0.3)+2*np.sin(5*Y))   
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```

The result looks like this:[image]

What are those lines that bump out of the surface coming from?
They are not in my data. Changing the resolution to 0.001 fixes them, but this makes the plotting really slow.

Comment: What are you values of Z?

Comment: I completed the code to make a MWE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, ax.plot_surface, ignores some of the data. The problem is that it does not ignore this data to draw the black lines. Therefore, the black lines are based on different data than the connecting blue patches.

This can be turned by passing optional arguments:

```
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z,cstride=1,rstride=1)
```

It is not clear to me what the idea behind the default settings is. I would be happy to be illuminated.

Comment: It's probably a performance issue, so you can see approximately what you will get before asking for the final "HD" version.